# Android: How is the pixel camera keeping its views in the exact same spot when rotating?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-camerax

I want to replicate the behaviour of the default camera app on my Pixel 7.

It behaves like this when rotating from portrait to landscape:

- navbar pill moves to new bottom of screen
- statusbar moves to new top of screen
- preview goes on without interruption (This would be nice but i would be okay without this)
- all buttons of the layout stay in exact same spot, and rotate 90 degrees

I'm using CameraX. The camera and its preview is in a fragment inside a viewpager2.

I tried the following things:

- Letting android handle rotation normally, and try to hide the rotation. The interuption of the preview is okay for me, but when i do this my layout is redrawn, causing all the views to be different sizes and in different locations.
  i'm hiding the transition like this:

```kotlin
private fun setRotationAnimation() {
    val rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_SEAMLESS
    val winParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams = window.getAttributes()
    winParams.rotationAnimation = rotationAnimation
    window.setAttributes(winParams)
}
```

- Adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" to the manifest, and then
  Using an old library that i found, https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout , to rotate the views onConfigChange. Unfortunatly, this doesn't work correctly with my constraintlayout.  The viewfinder does continue without interuption though like the pixel camera.

I also read that some camerapps fake rotating the screen by locking orientation to portrait and then only rotating the icons. That won't work for me as the other fragments will also stay in portrait, and the nav and status bar will remain in their portrait positions.

So my main question is, how can I keep views in the same spot while rotating when i have a complex layout? Can i copy their locations and restore them? Do i create two layout.xml files, one for portrait and one for landscape and painfully try to make them have all views in the same location on all screen sizes, but rotated 90 degrees? Can i inflate a view as if my device was in another orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check out if this is what you need? https://github.com/xizhang/camerax-seamless-rotation

"True" seamless might be difficult with `PreviewView` as it currently have glitches with transformation. But the user experience should be close.